# How to send data to a database with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, mongodb

I am currently making a website for microblogging that works like Twitter. Whenever I tweet something, it gets saved in my local storage, so if I exit the website and come back, the data is still there and I can see what I tweeted. However, when I ask my friend to go to the website, he cannot see the tweets. I am using Javascript, jQuery and the data is in a JSON format. How can I save this data and how can I read from it so everybody can see what has been tweeted on my website?

Right now, I get my tweetData from the local web storage and add them to the webpage by doing this:

```
      if(!localStorage.tweetData){
        localStorage.tweetData = [];
      } else {
        tweets = JSON.parse(localStorage.tweetData);
      }

      for(var i=0;i<tweets.length; i++){
        render(tweets[i]);
      }
```

I understand I need to send it to the a database, but how? I am using html/css, javascript, jquery. I read different places that php will be needed. I want to use mongoDB, I have created a sandbox on there, but I am totally lost on how to do the rest.  Please help point me in the right direction! I have googled, but most of it is about MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: Not really an answer, but http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php might help.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) or [this](https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/crud-operations-in-node-js-application-expresss-framework-using-mongodb-eb542f0ebe57) tutorial might help.

Comment: @darthaditya Thanks! It looks like something I want to build. However, the person is using Express and Node.js. I'm not very good at this, but is it possible to write Node/Express into my files?

Comment: @J.Doe of course. Think of Node as a layer between JS and low level system features. Express is a framework to organize your code and put it up on the web server. Don't worry too much about what Node and Express do under the hood. Just start building. You will understand along the way.

Comment: @darthaditya I see! So Node is like PHP (I was looking into that too)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I wouldn't spend my time learning a whole new language just to be able to connect to a DB. JS is the future IMO and the more you know JS libraries and frameworks the better.